# how do i solve this complex variables equation?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

How can I find all roots of logz=ipi/2?
I tried to use the formula Logz=lnr+itheta,
but I cannot do the next step.

Comment: $z=e^{i\pi /2}=i$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!